# Random order for parsing into struct using Boost Qi

Tags: c++, parsing, boost

Boost provides a neat example on how to very easily parse data into a struct that has been converted to a Boost Fusion tuple [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/tutorials/employee___parsing_into_structs.html) but I'm just wondering how do I adapt the code to allow for parsing of unordered data - i.e. referring to the employee example found in the link, we wish to be able to correctly parse `employee { "surname", "firstname", age, salary }`. This example is somewhat not so concrete since the signature of `age` is likely indistinguishable from `salary` and likewise for `surname` and `firstname`.

But say we adapt our parser to concretely parse input of the form `employee { surname = "Smith", firstname = "John", age = 34, salary = 60000 }` and wish to be able to input the four attributes in random order and allow for correct parsing. How do I go about that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following are related to your task:

- The [Permutation Parser (a ^ b)](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/operator/permutation.html)

  > The permutation operator, a ^ b, matches one or more operands (a, b, ... etc.) in any order

  However you'd need to add validation if your elements are not optional
- The [Keyword List Operator](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/spirit/repository/doc/html/spirit_repository/qi_components/operators/keyword_list.html) with the [`kwd` directive](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/spirit/repository/doc/html/spirit_repository/qi_components/directives/kwd.html) allow more fine grained control:

  **<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b39c5a0a508d7fb2)</kbd>**

  ```
  constraint_person_rule =
        kwd("name",1)               ['=' > parse_string ]
      / kwd("age"   ,1)             ['=' > int_]
      / kwd("size"   ,1)            ['=' > double_ > 'm']
      / kwd("favorite color",0,inf) [ '=' > parse_string ]
      ;
  ```